# Tmux asks for root password on every command

Tags: zsh, tmux

I recently had to reinstall my system and ever since I've been having a weird issue with tmux where it prompts me for my sudo password every time it creates a new pane or window (including when I first start it). It appears to make absolutely no difference whether I actually enter it or not; because the prompt happens *after* the pane/window was already created, I can just `Ctrl-C` out of the prompt if I want. I’m not sure if more functions are also affected which I just don't use but at least some of those I do use are definitely not (e.g. `source-file`).

On a sidenote, I also noted that since I changed my login shell to zsh after the reinstall, alias definitions in .zprofile do not carry over to interactive shells anymore, which they definitely did do under my previous system (although the file is definitely sourced as environment variables are set correctly even in the interactive shell). Maybe my shell environment got messed somehow and the tmux problem is just a side-effect of that?

Comment: Run `zsh -x` and `zsh -xl` and examine what's being run (`-x` for xtrace, `-l` for login). Probably calling `sudo` somewhere. Re zprofile: interactive shells don't necessarily source .zprofile; only login shells do (see "startup/shutdown files" section of `man zsh`).

Comment: Thanks! I found the issue (a ```sudo``` call to start a daemon in .zprofile). After having found a way which doesn't require ```sudo``` the problem disappeared. Still odd with the aliases though, especially since the ```sudo``` thing proves that .zprofile is definitely sourced by the interactive shell…

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the issue: I was using a `sudo` call to start a daemon in my .zprofile, so when the interactive shell sourced that it caused a sudo prompt. I found a workaround which doesn't require `sudo` which solved the problem.